# Android shadows pre Lollipop

Tags: android, compatibility, android-appcompat, shadows

In android 5.0+ exists property elevation, which add shadows for views. Who can suggest how make compatiblity with older versions 5.0< ? 9-patch not good idea, because in my app shadow everywhere and views different (with rounded corners, not rounded and e.t.c).

Comment: Use CardView. It will simulate the shadow effect on pre-lollipop devices

Comment: For ripple effect there are plenty of libraries that support up to api 11, very nice ripple effects and for shadows you can use cardviews they are better and supported by google, or else you can use a layered list drawable

Answer (score 0):

you can use card view from support. but if you meant Ripple animation you should draw it by yourself